# Multithreading brute force function

Tags: multithreading, python-2.7, brute-force

I'm wondering how I get use multiple threads to work with a brute force function, I'm currently just trying to learn how to take advantage of multithreading.

```
charset = string.ascii_letters + string.digits

def brute(real):
attempts = 0
for password_length in range(1, 9):
    for guess in itertools.product(charset, repeat=password_length):
        attempts += 1
        guess = ''.join(guess)
        if guess == real:
            return 'password is {}. found in {} guesses.'.format(guess, attempts)
        #print(guess, attempts)
```

The function is called using a print command

```
print(brute(apass))
```

apass is a variable set using another function and is a randomly generated password.

I am new to multithreading and I would like some help on how I can implement it into this code.

(this function was not made by me, I would just like to apply multithreading to it)

Comment: While you can do multithreading in Python, be aware that (in CPython at least) you won't get any speedup from doing so, due to Python's use of a Global Interpreter Lock (GIL).  If you hope to get a speedup from executing on multiple cores at once, take a look at the `multiprocessing` Python module instead.

Comment: How can I make use of said multiprocessing module? Should I import it?

Comment: Yes, you'll need to import it before you can use it.  I've never used it myself, my understanding is that it is designed to be used in a manner similar to how the thread module is used; the only difference being that each "thread"is actually a separate process (and therefore with its own separate GIL so it won't slow down the other "threads").  You can find documentation about how to use it online.